# Stored procedure to implement a search filter

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

I've implemented a stored procedure for a search process SQL Server 2008. I'm not sure if everything I created is correct. Also I'm wondering if this code has any leaks or vulnerability on SQL Injection. Here is my stored procedure:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Search_Dictionary]    Script Date: 08/09/2018 19:17:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Dictionary]
  @FilterBy int = NULL,
  @Name varchar(50) = NULL,
  @Code char(2) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT RecID, Status, Code, Name
    FROM Dictionary
    WHERE 
        (@FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE '%'+@Name+'%')
        OR 
        (@FilterBy = 2 AND Code = @Code)
        OR
        (@FilterBy = 3 AND @Name IS NULL AND @Code IS NULL);
END
```

Here is example on how I call this procedure:

```
EXEC Search_Dictionary @FilterBy = 1, @Name = "Grant", @Code = NULL;
```

I just want to prevent, if for example Filter By is 2 that should search query by Code column returns any result if user pass word Grant. In that case should return 0 records.

Also if anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the code please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A user could cause a dos attack by passing in complex like filters, you might want to sanitize the @name parameter. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Wildcard_Attacks_(OWASP-DS-001)

Answer (score 0):

## Vulnerabilities

There's **no way this stored procedure can be used for SQL injection**. The only way a stored procedure can allow SQL injection is if it allows an unsanitized user-entered string to be used to build a dynamic query using `sp_executesql` [(see docs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You're all safe on the vulnerabilities side.

## Functionality

The intended functionality with regards to the `FilterBy`s is not very clear in your posts so I'll try to explain how I think they'll behave:

Your procedure has three "modes" depending on what number is entered in to `FilterBy`.

1. For `FilterBy = 1`, the procedure would return any rows that have the `@Name` parameter inside the `Name` column. It ignores whatever is entered in to `@Code` in this instance. Note, if `@Name` is an empty string, **all records will be returned. Is that something you want?***
2. For `FilterBy = 2`, the procedure returns any rows where the `@Code` parameter matches the `Code` column entirely. In this instance, if `@Code` is `null` or empty, **no records are returned**. Whatever is passed in as `@Name` is ignored – whether it's `null` or not.
3. For `FilterBy = 3`, the procedure returns all rows, but only if `@Name` and `@Code` are `null`. If either of these parameters **not** `null`, no records are returned.

---

* If you don't want an empty string to return all rows, change the line to something like:

`(@FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE '%'+@Name+'%' AND @Name <> '')`

## Performance

Performance of this query largely depends on the size of the `Dictionary` table (obviously), and indexes. If you can afford the disk space and slower write speed, you could add an index to `Dictionary` with the `Code` column as the first indexed field. Make sure you include `RecID`, `Status`, and `Name` columns somewhere in that index. This would increase performance when using `FilterBy = 2`.

You could try adding another index with the `Name` field first, however this wouldn't do much for performance since you're using wildcards on the left side of the parameter when searching the `Name` field. [Here's a quick little explanation of why with a nice analogy](http://olicomber.co.uk/blog/b/Fast_wildcard_searching_in_SQL/).